# Set FILEVERSION/PRODUCTVERSION in configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to map the FILEVERSION/PRODUCTVERSION  to the selected configuration (e.g. "Release_CW32")?

I have to build against different versions of a DLL and that version should be reflected in the version of my own DLL, and I don't want to adapt the rc file each time I switch the configuration.

Comment: You can use macros in an .rc file.  And define them in Project + Properties, Resources, General, "Preprocessor Definitions" setting.  Which can have different values for different configurations.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't know macros work in there. Thank you very much!